# Evaluation of a contour integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I wonder whether Mathemtica can evaluate the contour integral of $\frac{2az+b}{az^2+bz+c}$ over the unit circle $|z| = 1.$ I do not have access to Mathemtica .Could we try something like :

````
(* Define the parameterization *)
z[t_] := Exp[I*t]

(* Evaluate the integral as a function of a, b, and c *)
integral[a_, b_, c_] := Integrate[(f[a, b, c, z[t]] * I * z[t]), {t, 0, 2*Pi}]```
````

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly routine:

```
f[z_] := (2 a z + b)/(a z ^2 + b z + c)
γ[t_] := Exp[I t]
Integrate[f[γ[t]] γ'[t], {t, 0, 2 π}]
```

Which gives you:

```
ConditionalExpression[I*Piecewise[{{2*Pi, Xor[Abs[(b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4*a*c])/a] < 2, Abs[(b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4*a*c])/a] < 2]}, 
    {4*Pi, Abs[(b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4*a*c])/a] < 2 && Abs[(b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4*a*c])/a] < 2}}, 0], 
 Abs[(b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4*a*c])/a] != 2 && Abs[(b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4*a*c])/a] != 2]
```

The reason for all the complexity here is because the roots may lie inside our outside or on the contour depending on $a,b,c$, and you may even have one outside, one inside. If the roots lie outside the contour, the result is of course zero because $f$ is analytic everywhere within the contour. If one is outside then you get $2\pi i$, and if both are inside, then you get $4\pi i$ in this case. If any of them are *on* the contour then the result is undefined.

If the roots lie inside, you can just use the residue theorem:

```
roots = Solve[Denominator[f[z]] == 0, z];
2 Pi I * Total[Residue[f[z], {z, z /. #}] & /@ roots]
(*Result: 4 I Pi *)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer is not complete. If one of the roots (or both roots) produced by `Solve[a z^2 + b z + c == 0, z]` belongs to the unit circumference `(Abs[(b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4*a*c])/a]]== 2` or `Abs[(b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4*a*c])/a] == 2)`, then the integral does not exist, but there exists its principal value.

Comment: @user64494 The answer _is_ complete insofar as the original question is worded - as the _integral_ is undefined which I mentioned. Your addition is a helpful further consideration however.

Comment: flinty (@ does not work.): I think you are not right. The question is "whether Mathem[a]tica can evaluate the contour integral of$\frac{2az+b}{az^2+bz+c}$ over the unit circle $|z|=1$".

Answer (score 1):

This is an improvement of the @flinty's answer. If one of the roots produced by `Solve[a z^2 + b z + c == 0, z]` belongs to the unit circumference `(Abs[(b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4*a*c])/a]]== 2` or `Abs[(b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4*a*c])/a] == 2)`, then the integral does not exist, but there exists its principal value.

```
f[z_] := (2 a z + b)/(a z^2 + b z + c);\[Gamma][t_] := Exp[I t];
Integrate[f[\[Gamma][t] *\[Gamma]'[t]], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
Assumptions ->  Abs[(b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4*a*c])/a] == 2 || 
Abs[(b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4*a*c])/a] == 2, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[ (2*I)*a*Piecewise[{{(-2*Pi)/Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c],  Abs[((-I)*b + Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])/a] >= 2 &&  Abs[(I*b + Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])/a] < 2},  {(2*Pi)/Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c], Abs[((-I)*b + Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])/a] <  2 && Abs[(I*b + Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])/a] >= 2}}, 0] +  b*Piecewise[{{(2*Pi)/c, Abs[((-I)*b + Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])/a] >= 2 &&  Abs[(I*b + Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])/a] >= 2},  {(2*(b^2 - 2*a*c + I*b*Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])*Pi)/ (c*(b^2 - 4*a*c + I*b*Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])),  Abs[((-I)*b + Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])/a] < 2 &&  Abs[(I*b + Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])/a] >= 2},  {(2*(-b^2 + 2*a*c + I*b*Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])*Pi)/ (c*(-b^2 + 4*a*c + I*b*Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])),  Abs[((-I)*b + Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])/a] >= 2 &&  Abs[(I*b + Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])/a] < 2}}, 0],  (Abs[(I*b + Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])/a]/2 < 1 ||  Abs[(I*b + Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])/a]/2 > 1) &&  (Abs[((-I)*b + Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])/a]/2 < 1 ||  Abs[((-I)*b + Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])/a]/2 > 1)]`

In order to consider the general case, the `PrincipalValue->True` option should be added (As the Russians say "You can't spoil porridge with butter".).

```
Integrate[f[\[Gamma][t] *\[Gamma]'[t]], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[(2*b*Pi)/c +  (2*I)*a*Piecewise[ {{0,  !(Xor[Sqrt[Abs[(I*b - Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])/a]]/Sqrt[2] < 1,  Sqrt[Abs[(I*b + Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])/a]]/Sqrt[2] < 1])},  {((2*I)*(I*b + Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])*Pi)/(I*b^2 - (4*I)*a*c +  b*Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c]), Sqrt[Abs[(I*b + Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])/a]]/ Sqrt[2] < 1}}, (2*(b + I*Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])*Pi)/ ((-I)*b^2 + (4*I)*a*c + b*Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])],  (Sqrt[Abs[(I*b - Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])/a]]/Sqrt[2] < 1 ||  Sqrt[Abs[(I*b - Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])/a]]/Sqrt[2] > 1) &&  (Sqrt[Abs[(I*b + Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])/a]]/Sqrt[2] < 1 ||  Sqrt[Abs[(I*b + Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c])/a]]/Sqrt[2] > 1)]`

Answer (score 0):

correct form (thanks @flinty)  of the integral

```
Integrate[(2 a z + b)/(a z^2 + b z + c)I Exp[I t] /. z -> Exp[I t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

evaluates `0`

Obviously this result (Mathematica v12.2) without any conditions isn't correct!

Comment: In 13.2 on Widows 10 `Integrate[(2 a z + b)/(a z^2 + b z + c) I Exp[I t] /. 
  z -> Exp[I t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]` results in `ConditionalExpression[
 I*Piecewise[{{2*Pi, Xor[Abs[(b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4*a*c])/a] < 2, 
      Abs[(b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4*a*c])/a] < 2]}, 
    {4*Pi, Abs[(b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4*a*c])/a] < 2 && 
      Abs[(b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4*a*c])/a] < 2}}, 0], 
 Abs[(b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4*a*c])/a] != 2 && 
  Abs[(b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4*a*c])/a] != 2]` as @flinty wrote.